# Where to find my website's source code?

Tags: php, code

My company ordered a website and we were given all usernames and passwords but I can't find the PHP source files and this is my first website assignment. I have no prior exposure to web technologies although I've been programming for a decade and know computer usage inside out. I tried to use the cPanel to find .php files but there aren't any. There are no MySQL databases either. I'm lost.

Answer (score 11):

You should have [FTP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File_Transfer_Protocol) login details somewhere in that list of usernames and passwords (if not call the supplier and ask for it) or if you have *full* cPanel access, you can [setup an account for yourself](http://docs.cpanel.net/twiki/bin/view/11_30/CpanelDocs/FTPAccounts).

FTP information should have:-

- FTP Address in the form of ftp.yourdomain.com, yourdomain.com, or an IP address)
- Username
- Password

Once you have the login information you'll need to download a free FTP client like [FileZilla](http://filezilla-project.org/). After you've set it up with the correct login details you should be able to access your website's root folder and the PHP source files.

Your MySQL database (if the website has one) should live under `'MySQL databases'` in the database section of cPanel. To manually edit entries (If you've no experience doing this, I suggest that you don't) click on `'phpMyAdmin'`.

[image: cPanel Screenshot]

Comment: Good answer. Only want to add, that the Windows explorer (not Internet-Explorer) can show FTP directories directly. So there is no need to install a tool, though it can be useful. Apart from the FTP-login, you normally get a second login for administration of the website (cPanel/mySQL).

Comment: @martinstoeckli Not only with IE. It's possible with many other browsers too.

Answer (score 0):

Try to go on cPanel File Manager, in directory public_html. Your files should be there.